# Como criar um arquivo dentro de um diretório?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, arquivo, diretório

```
import os

def main():
    checkDir = str(input('Escoha o diretório do arquivo Python: '))
    if os.path.exists(checkDir):
        print('O diretório existe!')
        print()
        nameDir = str(input('Digite o nome do novo arquivo: '))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Como eu poderia criar um "arquivo" dentro de um diretório em python(o usuário fala o nome do diretório, ele verifica se o diretório existe e se existir cria o arquivo com o nome dito pelo usuário)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partir da versão 3.4 do Python, recomenda-se utilizar a biblioteca `pathlib` para trabalhar com diretórios e arquivos.

```py
from pathlib import Path

directory = Path('test')

if directory.exists():
    file = directory / 'egg.txt'
    file.touch()
```

Se o diretório `test` existir será criado o arquivo `egg.txt` dentro dele.

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open(checkDir+'/'+nameDir , "w")
f.write("") # se quiser escrever algo dentro do arquivo, aqui entre as aspas
f.close()
```

Tenta assim, geralmente funciona.